# How to get the value for the primary key, which is filled by a default sequence in ms sql?

Tags: sql-server-2012

For identity

```
create table [Sites] (  
[SiteId] bigint  identity(1,1) NOT NULL,   
[Name] nvarchar(50)  NOT NULL)
ALTER TABLE Sites ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Sites PRIMARY KEY  ([SiteId])
```

i do

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Sites(Name) VALUES('test'); SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

and get SiteId value.

```
create table [Sites] (  
[SiteId] bigint  NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [seqMain]),   
[Name] nvarchar(50)  NOT NULL)
ALTER TABLE Sites ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Sites PRIMARY KEY  ([SiteId])
```

How get SiteId value if it filled by a default sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the [OUTPUT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.110).aspx).
That enables you to output values from a `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `MERGE` statement.

You use it like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Sites(Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.SiteId VALUES('test')
```